# Stream the desktop to web without any instalation

Tags: java, javascript, python, video-streaming

### The goal

User goes to a website, clicks a button, his screen is streamed to a server.

### Problems

Most of the solutions i found require an installation of some software to his/hers machine.
Either a streaming software, or software to make a virtual web cam output from your desktop.

### The big question

Is this even possible ? And, if yes in which technologies ? Would it be possible just through HTML5/Javascript combination, or would i have to use Java to make this possible ?

And if this is impossible, what would be the minimum viable program which a user has to install to make the "Log in -> click the button -> get the stream" possible ? Will a chrome/firefox extension suffice ? A python script ? Would it even be worth writing my own client side program for this ?

### Why am i even asking this ?

I have an idea of having all the programmers in my company use this to stream their screens,
but we all have different operating systems running. I only have 2 months of free time to make this happen. This is why i would like some opinions about the easiest way to make this happen, before i actually start coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible (or should be impossible) to stream a screen from a desktop to the server using only HTML5/Javascript. The reason this is so is because it would be a huge security violation -- a malicious website owner could then trick the user into streaming his screen without them knowing it, since there's a slight chance that the desktop screen could contain sensitive information. (What if their passwords are on the screen? What if they switch tabs to look at their bank account?)

In general, web browsers are heavily sandboxed so that a website can grab information only from their current tab/running instance.

---

Honestly, the easiest solution would be to not write a line of code at all and simply use a pre-existing program/service. I would recommend using perhaps [teamviewer](http://meeting.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) or [screenleap](http://www.screenleap.com/) -- they're both multi-platform, and should (I think?) support screensharing with multiple computers. You'll probably be able to find hundreds of other services online, since this is a very common problem people have.

However, if you do want to roll your own program for some reason, you could try looking at [red5-screenshare](http://code.google.com/p/red5-screenshare/), an open-source java program that launches from the browser.